# Set network.auth.use-sspi in Firefox with Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, kerberos, firefox, mitkerberos

I have downloaded the Group Policy templates and copied them to the appropriate location.

In `gpedit.msc` I have set:

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Mozilla > Firefox > Authentication > SPNEGO`

to include the required domain names and can see this reflected in Firefox when I open about:config.

However I also need to set `network.auth.use-sspi` to `false` and cannot work out which Group Policy setting does this.  Has anyone else been able to configure this?

Comment: Searching for `network.auth` on the Group Policy template github page, https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md only returns one result for a different setting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the older "[autoconfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig)" mechanism, which can be deployed through GPO "Preferences→Files" and can be used to enforce any possible about:config setting.

1. First stage: Deploy `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\autoconfig.js` with these two lines only:

   ```
   pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg.js");
   pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
   ```
2. Second stage: Deploy a file to `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\mozilla.cfg.js` with all settings that you want to enforce (formatted the same as the prefs.js file in your Firefox profile folder):

   ```
   // This file *must* start with a comment line.
   lockPref("network.auth.use-sspi", false);
   ```

(It is possible to add a third stage and make Firefox download further settings via HTTPS, by defining the `autoadmin.global_config_url` setting in the 2nd stage config. This is not necessary though, as the 2nd stage file will already be refreshed through GPO.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Firefox 81 and Firefox ESR 78.3 there is a way to set a lot of preferences using GPO or policies.json (including those with "network." prefix): [Mozilla policy templates \ Preferences](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#preferences)

- GPO / gpedit.msc: `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Mozilla > Firefox > Preferences`

> ```
> {
>    "network.auth.use-sspi": {
>        "Value": false,
>        "Status": "locked"
>    }
> }
> ```

- policies.json:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "Preferences": {
        "network.auth.use-sspi": {
            "Value": false,
            "Status": "locked"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If Preferences setting is used in both policies.json and GPO then only settings in GPO are used. Applied policies can be checked on the `about:policies` page.